# Ajax object IE: Youtube videos not properly loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, youtube

Once a first page is loaded nomally in my website, I request all other pages body contents with javascript ajax (ajaxObject).
I simply grab the body innerHTML with ajaxObject (javascript) and replace the actual one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(url) {
    var myRequest = new ajaxObject(url, uGotAResponse);
    myRequest.update('','GET');
}
function uGotAResponse(responseText,responseStatus) {
    //Create a temp div to be able to use getElementById on it.
    var theTempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    //put the grabbed body innerHTML into it.
    theTempDiv.innerHTML = responseText;
    //my pages are like <body><div id="divcontent">content of pages here</div></body>
    //so i get that div containing the innerHTML i really need.
    var allDiv = theTempDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i=0; i<allDiv.length; i++) {
            if (allDiv[i].getAttribute('id') == 'divcontent') {
                //i now replace the actual body innerHTML by the one i requested.
                document.getElementById('divcontent').innerHTML=allDiv[i].innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

On a page, I have youtube objects for embed videos:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/1ahKNnolR30" height="315px" width="420px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/1ahKNnolR30"></object>
```

In Firefox everything is fine if I either load the page using the address or with that ajax code.

With IE, it works only if I go to the page using the address.
When I try to use the ajax code the videos appear as the image below.
I tried it with IE tester, all versions give me the same error behaviour.

Does anyone have a fix for this maybe?

[image: Youtube video fails to load; blank(white) container.]

As you can see, it looks like the object video is there, but looks like IE is not interpreting it because its loaded by ajax.

Comment: Any code/html that you feel like sharing? Without those it'll be tricky for anyone to help you.

Comment: sorry, i used some html tags to name them, and so it stripped out those from visibility... thats why it wasn't that much clear yes... i fixed that and added some infos now. @FrankvanPuffelen